# How do I get legal help in the UK and is it free?

Tags: united-kingdom

How can I get advice about a everyday life situation, accidents or benefit in the United Kingdom?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about living in the UK and not expat issues.

Comment: I think this is fine, it's a bit similar to asking how to find a GP or medical services: if you're born there it's probably common sense, and you already have one since your birth. For the legal help: if you just arrived you might not even know what's the difference between a solicitor and a lawyer

Answer (score 3):

United Kingdom, not only has allot of free advice, but also more than a dozen specific regulating and helping bodies, that actually have your self in their best interest.

You can start of with the recenlty revamped [GOV.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/). You can really find most answers on this site or at least a starting point about more complicated issues.

If you are having some kind of civil problems, like money problems, abuse verbal/physical from family or stranger or general enquiries how to handle legal cases, there is a [citizens advice bureau](http://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/) website and there are offices near you.

Those are good starting points and usually these places will redirect you to a more specific body that deals better with your query. Like [Trading Standards](http://www.tradingstandards.gov.uk/), [National Accident Help line](http://www.national-accident-helpline.co.uk/) (for work or personal) and there are allot more!

If you have insurance of any kind, car or home, its worth taking Legal Advice cover too, it usually costs a few pound extra but you can call them up too, and if they see a good case you can be covered for millions of pounds of legal costs.

I have used many of these services, with reasonable attitude, where I felt I was put in the wrong. 90% cases were in my favour .

*FYI: It seems like the Automotive sector (Car sales, mechanics and dealers) in the UK is on the few sectors that are not regulated for standards. So if you have problems with bad workmanship that put your life at risk there is nothing you can do about it.*